# Cypress Touchpad issues

Tags: drivers, 16.04, mouse, touchpad, multi-touch

I'm having trouble with my touchpad on Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.
As soon as I try to move the cursor with the touchpad, dmesg shows a lot of errors. And the touchpad detects clicks (both right and left) randomly.

```
[  203.970980] psmouse serio2: Trackpad at isa0060/serio2/input0 - driver resynced.
[  204.000483] psmouse serio2: Trackpad at isa0060/serio2/input0 lost sync at byte 1
```

After some time the the driver seems to stop and it registers the touchpad as a generic PS/2 mouse.

```
[  204.692896] psmouse serio2: issuing reconnect request
[  206.691622] psmouse serio2: cypress_ps2: Reconnect: Unable to initialize Cypress absolute mode.
[  207.885887] psmouse serio2: Failed to enable mouse on isa0060/serio2
[  207.946932] input: PS/2 Generic Mouse as /devices/platform/i8042/serio2/input/input27
```

In this mode the touchpad works, but of course I'm missing multitouch features like two finger scrolling.
Is there any chance to get the cypress driver working?

I've already tried different kernel parameters that worked for other people:
`i8042.nomux=1` and `i8042.reset` didn't help.

Kernel: `4.4.0-24-generic`

[dmesg output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/17978203/)

[/proc/bus/input/devices before driver failing](http://paste.ubuntu.com/17978374/)

Comment: I suggest filing a bug to launchpad. But before doing that try new mainline kernels, like 4.6.

Comment: ok thanks, I tried 4.6 but no difference. I will report the bug as soon as I've got more time again.

Comment: how to try a different kernel (e.g. 4.6)? I have the same problem with this trackpad. Was the bug submitted?